# Match a domain in a urls ending with specified word

Tags: regex

I have a list of urls I need to sort. I will try to explain what I need.

Example:

```
http://test56.testdom.com/dev123/85056704/test/test.php?something=else&t=1
http://test14.testdoma.tv/dev234/93181034/test/backup.zip
http://test22.testdomai.me/dev945/23145034/test/test.zip
http://test12.testdomain.co.uk/dev184/95342034/test/random?random=123&stuff=true
http://test76.testdomains.de/dev643/13453534/test/random.zip
```

I need a regex to match the full domain name, in URLs ending with `zip`, like this:

```
test14.testdoma.tv
test22.testdomai.me
test76.testdomains.de
```

So basically: "if there's a `zip`, match from `test` to `/`".

How can I write a regex like this?

Comment: \/\/([^\/]+).*?\.zip$ @VixinG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Notepad++, you don't get output like you'd in any programming language.
But you can use find and replace with a regex, i.e.:

**FIND:**    `https?://(.*?)/.*\.zip`
**REPLACE:** `$1`

The above, will replace all url's ending in zip, with the corresponding domain.

**SUBJECT:**

```
http://test56.testdom.com/dev123/85056704/test/test.php?something=else&t=1
http://test14.testdoma.tv/dev234/93181034/test/backup.zip
http://test22.testdomai.me/dev945/23145034/test/test.zip
http://test12.testdomain.co.uk/dev184/95342034/test/random?random=123&stuff=true
http://test76.testdomains.de/dev643/13453534/test/random.zip
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
http://test56.testdom.com/dev123/85056704/test/test.php?something=else&t=1
test14.testdoma.tv
test22.testdomai.me
http://test12.testdomain.co.uk/dev184/95342034/test/random?random=123&stuff=true
test76.testdomains.de
```

---

**UPDATE:**

With **JavaScript** you can use this regex:

```
var myregexp = /https?:\/\/(.*?)\/.*\.zip/img;
```

---

And for **PHP**:

```
$urls = <<< EOF
http://test56.testdom.com/dev123/85056704/test/test.php?something=else&t=1
http://test14.testdoma.tv/dev234/93181034/test/backup.zip
http://test22.testdomai.me/dev945/23145034/test/test.zip
http://test12.testdomain.co.uk/dev184/95342034/test/random?random=123&stuff=true
http://test76.testdomains.de/dev643/13453534/test/random.zip
EOF;
    preg_match_all('%https?://(.*?)/.*\.zip%im', $urls, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches[1]); $i++) {
        echo $matches[1][$i];
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try following regex:

```
/http:\/\/([^\/ ]+).+\.zip/g
```

See example on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/kU0hP7/1).